# Python , getopt , how to get a list

Tags: python, command-line-arguments

I'm trying to use the library `getopt` in order to catch a list of path given from command line something like this :

```
python script.py -l ["a","b","c","d","e"] -p 80 ....
```

what I wrote is this:

```
def getValue(self):
        ''' 
            get value from command line and initialize 
            variable !
        '''

        try:
            opts,args = getopt.getopt( self.args ,                                  
                                       "hl:us:r:p:" ,
                                       ['help','local_path','update',"remote_host","remote_path","parameter"])
        except getopt.GetoptError as err:
            print(str(err))
            self.usage()

## ----------------- SETTING VARIABLE PASSED BY COMMAND LINE ------------------ ##      

        for opt,arg in opts:
        #----------------------------------------------------------      
            if opt in ("-l","--local_path"):
                self.local_path = arg
                if DEBUG:   
                    print('local path: ',self.local_path)
        #-----------------------------------------------------------      
            elif opt in ("-h", "--help"):
                self.usage()
        #-----------------------------------------------------------      
            elif opt in ("-s", "--remote_host"):
                self.remote_host = arg
                if DEBUG:
                    print('Simulation host: ', self.remote_host)
        #-----------------------------------------------------------      
            elif opt in ("-r", "--remote_path"):
                self.remote_path = arg
                if DEBUG:
                    print('Simulation path: ', self.remote_path)
        #-----------------------------------------------------------      
            elif opt in ("-p", "--parameter"):
                self.parameter = arg
                if DEBUG:
                    print('Simulation parameter: ',self.parameter)
        #-----------------------------------------------------------
            elif opt in ("-u","--update"):
                #if self.remote_host and self.remote_path:
                    self.update()
        #-----------------------------------------------------------
            else:
                assert False, "Unhandled Option"
        #-----------------------------------------------------------
```

but unfortunately this take just single value for each opts (-l, -p ....) 
how can reach my aim ?
thanks in advance !!

Comment: Don't use `getopt`; it's mainly intended to ease porting code in another language that already uses it. For new code, use `argparse`.

Comment: If you intend for the single argument to `-l` to be a list literal, you need to quote the entire thing first; `[` has special meaning to the shell. `python script.py  -l '["a", "b"]'` Then inside your code, you'll still need to *parse* the string as a Python literal using `ast.literal_eval`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've simplified your script a bit to specifically address your question about passing a list of arguments from the command line.

One option you have is to specify the same flag multiple times to send several arguments into your program. For example:

```
import getopt
import sys

opts, args = getopt.getopt(
    sys.argv[1:],
    'hl:p:',
    ['help', 'local_path', 'parameter'],
)

local_paths =  []
for opt, arg in opts:
    if opt in ('-l', '--local_path'):
        local_paths.append(arg)
        print(opt + ': ' + arg)
    if opt in ('-p', '--parameter'):
        print(opt + ': ' + arg)

print('local_paths: ' + str(local_paths))
```

Used as follows:

```
$ python script.py -la -lb -p 80
-l: a
-l: b
-p: 80
local_paths: ['a', 'b']
```

Another option (if you must pass the list itself via the command line to a single instance of the flag) is to use some sort of serialization. JSON is up to the task but you could also use csv or others. Example:

```
import getopt
import json
import sys

opts, args = getopt.getopt(
    sys.argv[1:],
    'hl:p:',
    ['help', 'local_path', 'parameter'],
)

for opt, arg in opts:
    if opt in ('-l', '--local_path'):
        list_arg = json.loads(arg)
        print(opt + ': ' + str(list_arg))
    if opt in ('-p', '--parameter'):
        print(opt + ': ' + arg)
```

```
$ python script.py -l '["a","b"]' -p 80
-l: ['a', 'b']
-p: 80
```

Note the quotes (`'`) around the JSON after the `-l` flag (`'["a","b"]'`). This notation "protects" the argument from being evaluated by bash.

If you pass the argument as you have done in your example, python still receives a single argument but it does not quite work as I think you intend:

```
import getopt
import sys

opts, args = getopt.getopt(
    sys.argv[1:],
    'hl:',
    ['help', 'local_path'],
)

for opt, arg in opts:
    if opt in ('-l', '--local_path'):
        print(opt + ': ' + arg)
        print('type: ' + str(type(opt)))
```

```
$ python script.py -l ["a","b"]
-l: [a,b]
type: <class 'str'>
```

The argument for the `-l` flag is literally the string `"[a,b]"` in python. This happens because bash evaluated the expression `["a","b"]` before running the script, so now deserialization in python is a bit trickier. It is probably worth avoiding this way and sticking with a standard serialization pattern.

To clarify the notation above from [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/getopt.html#getopt.getopt):

> `shortopts` is the string of option letters that the script wants to recognize, with options that require an argument followed by a colon (':')

So `hl:` means we accept `-h` and `-l`, but `-l` must have an argument, otherwise we will get something like:

```
getopt.GetoptError: option -l requires argument
```

Comment: I dont understand how 'hl:p:' correlates to the arguments. Could you explain this.

Comment: See my edits on `shortopts` above. I also I fixed a typo to add clarity